# Talking with/against the dead

Tags: halacha, commentaries, death, deuteronomy

If a beloved one has passed away, is it allowed or prohibited to talk against this soul? For example is it allowed to say goodbey, or to say you will mis him/her? I know there is a prohibition against consulting or calling up the death (Devarim 18:11) but in the case of bereavement, grieving and mourning is it allowed to talk in such a way in order to process the loss?

Could it be possible there’s a difference between talking with and talking against a deceased person?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "talking against"? Do you mean just talking in the presence of the deceased without addressing them, actually addressing them, or saying negative things about them?

Comment: @Jay It’s a duplication, thank you for sharing

Comment: Actually, G-d bans talking with the dead not because it is possible but because it is not. This is the view of the Jewish rationalist, Abraham ibn Ezra. He compares it with the prohibition of idolatry. G-d bans idolatry not because other gods exist but because they do not and the practice is harmful and useless. Similarly, G-d bans consulting with the dead. It is impossible and no one has ever been able to do it. For example, King Saul had a hallucination.

Comment: Also, devils and demons do not exist, for it is illogical to suppose that G-d would create 'dark forces.' But if it helps psychological, I suppose one could imagine, but know that it is only your imagination and not a real happening.